# Google Chrome lost the up-to-date Flash Player

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome, flash, pepperflash

I'm in Xubuntu LTS, Google Chrome stable latest.

I have been using Xubuntu without Adobe Flash package for quite some time, and things works fine.
Then this one day, for some reason I don't remember, I installed the legacy Flash Player package (I think it's `flashplugin-installer`?), and suddenly ALL blink-based browsers (Google Chrome, Opera, Vivaldi) lost Flash Player in their plugin setting page, and can not play Flash contents.

So I Googled, installed `adobe-flashplugin` and `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` instead, and Flash plugins returned -- except for Google Chrome.

Now in my Chrome, all flash contents will show a warning "Adobe Flash Player is out of date" (even if I disable Flash Player in chrome://plugins), and Chrome refused to play them.

Some version info:

- Current Xubuntu version: 16.04.01
- Current Flash Player version: 23.0.0.207
- In chrome://plugins
  Adobe Flash Player - Version 23.0.0.185
  Location: internal-not-yet-present
  Type: PPAPI (out-of-process)
- In chrome://components
  Adobe Flash Player - Version 0.0.0.0
- In chrome://version
  Google Chrome: 54.0.2840.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
  Flash: 23.0.0.185

If, however, I do this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/ /opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash # There's no PepperFlash folder by default
```

then chrome://components will show

> Adobe Flash Player - Version 23.0.0.207

But chrome://plugins and chrome://version still show `23.0.0.185`, and Flash contents still show the "out of date" warning and Chrome still refuse to play them.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome with no avail. Any way I can fix this?

---

Edit:

It seems this relates to [how Google Chrome distribute Flash Player in version 54+](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2221587), so I used the "Check for update" button in chrome://components, and it says

> Updater started

But eventually says

> Component not updated

Linking everything from `/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/` to `~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash/` didn't seem to help.

---

Finally:

It seems Chrome insist on using proxy `"DIRECT"` when it checks for component update (`https://clients2.google.com/service/update2?cup2key=...`, see it in `chrome://net-internals/#events`), despite me setting PAC proxy in `dconf` and Chrome extension, so our lovely GFW happily blocked the request. Found a VPN and the component successfully upgraded.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Nevermind, sorry, my bad. I'm a bit behind the times :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited 2017-02-28**

It has happened some things with Flash recently:

- Previously Flash was shipped with Google Chrome, but it isn't any longer in the same way as before.
- Hence the `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` package is currently broken, even if it is about to be fixed (new download location).
- Chrome ships Flash bundled with Chrome, and there is nothing extra which needs to be done if you use Chrome.

`adobe-flashplugin` provides Flash plugins for other browsers, both Firefox and Chromium/Opera/Vivaldi.

Try this:

- Close Google Chrome.
- Remove both `adobe-flashplugin` and `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`.

  ```
  sudo apt purge adobe-flashplugin pepperflashplugin-nonfree
  ```
- Open Google Chrome and check if it made a difference.

My experience is that you may need to close and reopen Chrome a couple of times before Flash starts working.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info and direction, but this doesn't make any difference. I even `apt purge google-chrome-stable` and re-download and reinstall Chrome again, but before and after I install `adobe-flashplugin` chrome://version still says I have flash 23.0.0.185. Does the sequence of installing Chrome and flashplugin matter?

Comment: @Passerby: Don't know. But what version do you have according to [this page](https://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/)? The version stated there is the version Chrome actually uses.

Comment: I've tried installing flashplugin first and then Google Chrome and still get the same result. I can't see the version from adobe's website because it uses flash to check version, and Chrome keep complaining that flash is out of date and refuse to run. chrome://plugins and chrome://version insist I have 23.0.0.185 no matter what I do; chrome://components says I have 0.0.0.0 (23.0.0.207 if I do the `ln` in question). The current version should be 23.0.0.207

Comment: @Passerby: What does the command `locate libpepflashplayer.so` output? For me it shows the file path `/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so`. Possibly you have the folder `~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash`. If so, try to delete that folder.

Comment: Yes I have `~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash`, deleted it before, but when Chrome launches it gets created again. Then I found [this post](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2221587), and tried "updating" flash in chrome://components, but it eventuallys says "Component not updated". I tried linking `/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/*` to this folder and it didn't help.

Comment: I think I should add that I live inside GFW. I use a proxy and a PAC file to work around that, but I wonder if the updater goes to `*.google.com/*` and it respects proxy setting. I'm using an extension to manage Chrome's proxy setting, and this works for all "normal" browsing, but I'm not sure if it works for these "internal" downloading.

Comment: @Passerby: I have `~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash/21.0.0.197/libpepflashplayer.so` which is left from when I hade Crome installed (which I haven't currently). So possibly you should create and link to `~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash/23.0.0.207`. Besides that I'm out of ideas, unfortunately.

Comment: It turns out that Chrome insist on using proxy "DIRECT" when checking for component update, no matter what PAC I set in `dconf` and extension, as I guessed. Still, thank you very much for the information.

Comment: @Passerby: They keep changing things, and I just updated my answer to the latest that I know about.