# Flash player: When I install, my browser still tells me I need to install Flash

Tags: google-chrome, video, flash

In the terminal I added the universe repository and then issued command `sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin`.  It seemed to install correctly.  I then installed Google Chrome by finding the appropriate repository and issuing `sudo apt install google-chrome-stable`.  After that, I open Chrome and try to play a video on HBO GO, but it tells me that I need to have Flash installed.  I then found these instructions: [Google Chrome lost the up-to-date Flash Player](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855214/google-chrome-lost-the-up-to-date-flash-player)

However, after purging the installed libraries and restarting Chrome, then trying again to play the video, it still says that I need to install Flash.

Any suggestions?

[Edit: Update, I clicked the link that pops up for getting Flash--I initially figured this shouldn't be useful since it'll just take me to Adobe's page where I'm supposed to download things rather than use the package manager, which seemed like a bad idea.  But I clicked it just to try something, and it refreshed and no longer tells me I need to download Flash.  However, now, it just hangs on the video with the "buffering" image and never actually plays the video.]

Comment: Google Chrome is shipped with Flash bundled, so no plugin needed. Just be patient and let Chrome accomplish its update, and it will probably start working.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Hm, it's been "buffering" or "loading" or whatever, for over a half-hour on an ethernet connection.  I think something is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Latest Adobe Flash version is 30.0.0.113 (see [official page](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/about/)).

It is included in latest Google Chrome 67.0.3396.79.

So *google-chrome-stable* package should have *67.0.3396.79-1* version.

You need to run `sudo apt update` following by `sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: Doesn't work.  All packages are up to date, everything that can be upgraded is.  Still, when I try to play the video, it just hangs on the "loading" icon and never plays.  I've even closed Chrome and uninstalled it, and then reinstalled it, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: And indeed, when I right-click on the video and see the version of Flash, it is the latest.

Comment: You can ask support on your VIdeo hosting. If [Adobe's page](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/about/) sees up to date flashplayer, we can not do anything. Also it may be [DRM issue](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Flash_DRM_content).